# Перевод синхронной функции в асинхронную

Tags: python, requests, bs4, aiohttp, urllib

Я не знаю как переписать свой код в асинхронку, в основном мне нужно реализовать

```
requests.get(url).text
urllib.parse.quote_plus(str)
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text, "html.parser")
allNews = soup.findAll('tag', class_='some class')
```

с помощью aiohttp, то есть надо сделать это всё без использования bs4, requests, urllib только на aiohttp, прошу помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: В документации по aiohttp первый же пример кода показывает, как получить текст страницы: https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/index.html#getting-started Парсинг без bs4 - ну это проблематично будет. aiohttp вам заменит только requests и urllib (возможно)

Comment: Можно использовать  aiohttp, asyncio и lxml

Comment: Поясните почему такие ограничения? Это тест ваших знаний или просто вам так захотелось?

Comment: Вообще это я планирую сделать бота который будет выводить тексты песен из запросов в гугл, вчера протестировал, там у меня эта функция где были запросы в гугл была синхронной и мне в чате программистов сказали что надо полностью переделать в асинхронку, а то в синхронке бот сразу умрет от 10 человек